# How to get json data instead of the HTML Page using Guzzle?

Tags: html, laravel, http, request, guzzle

I'm trying to connect my API to my website to retrieve data. When the user is connected, there is a call to the API to get the data in a JSON format but the response give me the html of my API login page.

I'm using Guzzle 6 and laravel 5.8 for this.

```
public static function getClient()
{

    $url = config( 'test.default_api_url' );
    $client = new Client([ 'base_uri' => $url, 'timeout'  => 200.0 ]);
    return $client;

}

public static function callApiOnce($method, $route, $options)
{
    $client = self::getClient(); 
    $response = $client->request($method, $route, $options)->getBody()->getContents();
    if( $response )
    {
        $contents = (string) $response;
        return $contents;
    }
    return false;
}

public static function callApiMany($routes)
{
    $response = [];
    foreach($routes as $route => $settings)
    {
        $json = self::callApiOnce(
            $settings['method'],
            $settings['route'],
            $settings['options']
        );
        $response[$route] = $json;
    }
    return $response;
} 

public function getHomeData()
{
    $routes = [
        "home_tile_1" => [
            "method" => "GET",
            "route" => "aggregates",
            "options" => [
                "query" => [
                    "user_id" => $_SESSION[ "userId" ],
                    "api_token" => $_SESSION[ "api_token" ],
                    "type" => "monthly",
                    "month" => "last"
                ],
                "headers" => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $_SESSION[ "api_token" ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    
    
    $response = ApiRequestController::callApiMany( $routes );
    
    return response()->json( [ "success" => true, "data" => $response ] );
}
```

I expected to get the data as a JSON format bu i only get the API HTML page ...

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: There are a few layers here, Arnaud. Where are you expecting JSON? In the `$response` variable in your `getHomeData` method?

Comment: Hi, yes i want to get the JSON in $response. It work on Postman, i get the JSON without adding headers...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send the data to API by json_encode ?
and also use the json_decode to get the output .

And if possible, please post the error or html page you got

Comment: I find what was the problem ... Just a route problem ... It's a homemade API. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ArnaudCartailler please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find what was the problem ... Just a route problem ... It's a homemade API. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For anyone wondering what he meant by 'route problem', he most likely made a typo in his route. I had the exact same problem with Laravel Passport, using Guzzle to make post request to oauth/token endpoint. My problem was, the endpoint url is 'h t t p s://myweb.com', but i missed the 's' of 'https', hence I was making request to 'h t t p://myweb.com' the whole time! Anyone experiencing this problem, please double check your endpoint URL is correct or not, it is a route problem!!! Spent 4 hours trying to figure this out.